# How to get values of date & time fields as millisecs from netsuite suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In Suitescript 2.0, I can able to get record by id.

RESTlet:

```
    var response = record.load({
        type: resourceType,
        id: context.recordId
    });
```

Response:

```
{
   ...
   "starttime": "6:00 pm",
   "startdate": "13 FEBRUARY, 2019"
   ...
}
```

How to get all date & time values as millisecs in Netsuite using suitescript 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

NetSuite has 2 types of date fields, *date* and *dateTime*.

Date field does not contain time details, so you cannot get time from these fields like trandate etc. Whereas if you use `getValue` on dateTime field, NetSuite returns a date object and you can `toISOString` or any other method from [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class.

Comment: Actually, We are using the getValue() and it is not returning the date object with proper timezone. 

If the user/account timezone is IST, the date returned is in PST. 
format.format(), format.parse() both not considering the timezone we are passing(IST).

Comment: AFAIK, netsuite saves dateTime in server format(i.e netsuite datacenter), so you can't really do much there. But for converting dateTime to correct/required timezone you can use js-libraries like [moment](https://momentjs.com/).